# What is the default (official?) Bower registry URL?

Tags: bower

What is the main Bower registry URL?

We're trying to set up Bower to use our registry first, then the "official" Bower registry second.

We've created our own little Bower registry based on the endpoints exposed in [bower/registry][1](https://github.com/bower/registry). Works great.

Based on [this doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1APq7oA9tNao1UYWyOm8dKqlRP2blVkROYLZ2fLIjtWc/edit#heading=h.nfim1ufbrtm4), it looks like we need to create a .bowerrc file with an array of registries like

```
{
  "registry": {
    "search": [
      "http://myCustomRegistry/api",
      "theMainBowerRegistry"
    ]
  }
}
```

Works fine for use my custom registry, but I can't find the URL for the main Bower registry. Anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default registry URL is => https://bower.herokuapp.com

Comment: It's quite surprising that the registry is at HerokuApp.com. Why not at bower.com? I saw the bower.herokuapp.com a few places, but just assumed that this could not be the official registry.

Answer (score 10):

Now it is https://registry.bower.io

https://twitter.com/bower/status/908359136601133056

See the explanation https://gist.github.com/sheerun/c04d856a7a368bad2896ff0c4958cb00

Answer (score 3):

The default registry as of now is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bower/components/1.0.0 for anyone looking in 2017. Entering this into my .bowerrc file solved my ECONNRESET errors. Bower moved away from the herokuapp repository it was using to Github.

The link to Bower's link on Twitter describing this move is linked below.

https://twitter.com/bower/status/796046017133211648

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's just https://bower.herokuapp.com. `/packages` is part of the REST API routes, which would create redundant URL segments in your Bower requests (e.g. https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/bootstrap`).

Comment: I don't get the "create redundant URL segments ..." part at all. Also the URL was wrong, I removed the doubly "/packages".