# Is there a Bower registry REST API

Tags: package, bower

I cannot find the documentation for a REST api anywhere. I want to query it to find license information.

This question ([What is the default (official?) Bower registry URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069093/what-is-the-official-bower-registry-url)) indicates you can use:

https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/...

and

https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/...

but is there any documentation on the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there isn't? It looks like the official search engine just pulls everything in (1.6mb gzipped) and then lets you search packages on the client, so I don't see why it would be set up to be queryable. Also there doesn't appear to be any license information there anyway. Many packages will put this in the package.json or just in a readme somewhere so it probably wouldn't be that useful if they did.