# How do I figure out who maintains a bower packge?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower

`bower info` doesn't seem to show this information.

```
➔ bower info sugar --verbose
bower sugar#*                   cached git://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar.git#1.4.1
bower sugar#*                 validate 1.4.1 against git://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar.git#*

{
  name: 'sugar',
  version: '1.4.1',
  main: './release/sugar.min.js',
  ignore: [
    '/docs',
    '/lib',
    '/script',
    '/test',
    '/performance',
    '.gitignore',
    '.npmignore',
    '.travis.yml',
    'package.json'
  ],
  dependencies: {},
  homepage: 'https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar'
}

Available versions:
  - 1.4.1
  - 1.4.0
  - 1.3.9
  - 1.3.8
  - 1.3.7
  - 1.3.6
  - 1.3.5
  - 1.3.4
  - 1.3.3
  - 1.3.2
  - 1.3.1
  - 1.2.5
  - 1.2.4
  - 1.2.3
  - 1.2.2
  - 1.2.1
  - 1.1.3
  - 1.1.2
  - 1.1.1
  - 0.9.5
  - 0.9.4
  - 0.9.3
  - 0.9.2
  - 0.9.1
You can request info for a specific version with 'bower info sugar#<version>'
```

Comment: https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar?

Comment: https://github.com/andrewplummer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the maintainer is the owner of the github page of the Sugarjs - http://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar.

It's a good practice putting information about the maintainer on the authors field of the bower.js, usually you can get on the bower.json file.

Comment: Well I meant, who maintains the registered bower package, not who maintains the code. But I see here there is no sense of ownership of the registered bower package http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about who maintains the registry, rather than who maintains the code, it depends on which registry you are using.  By default, you are probably using https://bower.herokuapp.com, but you can use a private registry as well.  See [What is the default (official?) Bower registry URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069093/what-is-the-official-bower-registry-url) for a little more info.

Comment: thanks! fascinating that i never once encountered that in my relatively extensive searching...

Comment: Looks like this now redirects to http://bower.io/search/ -- maybe only when accessing via browser?